# how to hide a child div and add class name for parent using jquery on click

Tags: jquery, show-hide

```
    <li>
    <h4 class="title-exp-coll title-expand">
    <span class="exp-coll"></span>Bookmarks</h4>
    <div class="item-list">
    <ul>      
    <li class="first"><div>first Asset</div></li>
    <li><div>Latest Updates</div></li>
    <li><div>asset image</div></li>
    <li><div>test Asset 1</div></li>
    </ul></div>
    </li>

    <li>
    <h4 class="title-exp-coll title-expand">
    <span class="exp-coll"></span>Menu</h4>
    <p>No menu.</p>
    </li>

    <li>
    <h4 class="title-exp-coll title-expand">
    <span class="exp-coll"></span>Main Menu</h4>
    <div class="item-list">
    <ul>      
    <li><div>asset image</div></li>
    <li><div>test Asset 1</div></li>
    </ul></div>
    </li>
```

Below is the code:

My expected result is when I click on the **span class "exp-coll"** inside the `<h4>` tag

1. the corresponding **next** `<div>` or **next** `<p>` tag should hide
2. **in h4 tag the class "title-expand" should be removed and "title-collapse" should be added.**
3. in the mean time when i click the **span class "exp-coll"** second time the opposite should happen.
4. That is the corresponding **next** `<div>` or **next** `<p>` tag should **SHOW**
5. **in h4 tag the class "title-collapse" should be removed and "title-expand" should be added.**

How can this be done using jQuery..

Any help will be thankful and grateful...

Comment: You should have pasted some code to get an idea of what you are doing . you cant just post your requirement and ask people to do your job.

Comment: @ankur , maybe he can not do that himself :(

Comment: @AliForoughi you got it right. you made his day by posting the detailed answer.

Comment: @ankur: I agree with your statement.. But it doesn't mean that i asking some other people to do my job.. The only reason i am posting my question in SOF i am getting many type of approaches to solve the same problem.. So many new things i learned from it. That's what the case and the least thing is that i will not ask anyone to do my job...

Comment: @ankur: Kindly find my posted answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
$(function(){

    $("h4 span.exp-coll").click(function(){

        if($(this).parents("h4").hasClass("title-expand")){
           //number 1
           $(this).next("div").hide();
           //Number 2
           $(this).parents("h4").removeClass("title-expand").addClass("title-collapse");               
        }
        else{

           //number 4
           $(this).next("div").show();
           //Number 5
           $(this).parents("h4").removeClass("title-collapse").addClass("title-expand");           

        }

    });

});
```

Good luck

Comment: @@Ali Foroughi: You only mistake is that you have set flag = true in the beginning.. So, ti will work only on hide and when you click second time it will parse in to the else class.. Kindly change it.. So that i can mark as answer...

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's .next() and .toggle() functions! Though, fadetoggle looks a little better:

http://api.jquery.com/next/

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("span.exp-coll").click(expand_collapse);   

function expand_collapse() {
        flag = $(this).parent("h4").hasClass("title-expand");
        if(flag){
             $(this).parents('li').children('div, p, form').slideUp('slow');
             $(this).parents("h4").removeClass("title-expand").addClass("title-collapse");
             flag = false;
        }
        else{
             $(this).parents('li').children('div, p, form').slideDown('slow');
             $(this).parents("h4").removeClass("title-collapse").addClass("title-expand");
             flag = true;
        }
    }
```